# How to bind javascript to all related elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a placeholder to work on IE. The issue is that my page loads some elements via Ajax, but Javascript is loaded only once. Therefore the Ajax loaded input fields do not have placeholders (because those elements were not loaded when the Javascript executed).

I was trying to make it so that the script is bind to all input text elements with placeholder and not just to currently loaded, but I am not sure what am I doing wrong.

```
if(!$.support.placeholder) {

    $('[placeholder]').on('focus', function() {
        var input = $(this);
        if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
            input.val('');
            input.removeClass('placeholder');
        }
    }).on('blur', function() {
        var input = $(this);
        if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
            input.addClass('placeholder');
            input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
        }
    }).blur();

}
```

Comment: Replace 'on' with 'live' and it should work for new elements too.

Comment: @cjc343 `live()` is deprecated - you should use `on()` in the correct way

Comment: Not sure how I've missed that, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
if(!$.support.placeholder) {

    $('#closestStaticParent').on('focus', '[placeholder]' function() {
      var input = $(this);
      if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
        input.val('');
        input.removeClass('placeholder');
      }
    }).on('blur', '[placeholder]' function() {
      var input = $(this);
      if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
        input.addClass('placeholder');
        input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
      }
    }).blur();

}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working. By the way, how to I blur the new element? I tried `on('load'..` and `on('ready'..` but they don't seem to work.

Comment: you are welcome, but you might want to ask a new question for a new issue - that might be helpful in the future for those who will face the same problem